# How to draw layered class diagram in Visual Studio following DDD?

Tags: oop, uml, domain-driven-design, class-diagram

We are trying to model our new ordering application using DDD. 
I see a window called `Layer Explorer` in visual studio.

1. Can we use this feature to model complex business application
   spanned over multiple layers?
2. Is there any advantage of using this
       compared to representing layers in flat block diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I would stay away from tooling to help you model. Whiteboards, IKEA paper rolls, and good markers are the way forward ("@ziobrando style" TM). Nobody is waiting for another class diagram or "architecture" diagram. Communication, modeling behavior, validating what you came up with together with the domain expert using his scenarios, etc ... are far more important than static diagrams. Structural models are good at establishing part of the glossary, i.e. the nouns of the domain you're solving problems for. At best they show you the relationship between two nouns and cardinality may give away some hints as well.

Probably not the answer you wanted to read ...